What is the origin, precise meaning, and purpose of labelling the string section "Archi" in an orchestral score?
In an orchestral score for Rachmaninoff's 2nd Piano concerto I see that in subsequent pages (page 2-10) the string section (2 violins, 1 viola, 1 cello, 1 contrabass) is labelled "Archi", only to be labelled with individual instruments again in:

Pages 11-12: Smaller string section Violin 1 + Cello + Contrabass
Pages 42-44: Rachmaninoff breaks the Cello into two staves until page 45 (the final measures of the 1st movement), where the Cello merges into one staff and he goes back to labelling the string section "Archi".

Snapshots from the score:

Pages 1 and 2:
 
Pages 11 and 42:
 

The questions:

Meaning:

What is it an abbreviation for, and in what language?

Is "Archi" simply a shorthand for a system of 5 staves for Violin 1 + Violin 2 + Viola + Cello + Contrabass?  For example, can "Archi" be used when there is only one violin part (i.e. 4 staves)?  Or is there another meaning besides that shorthand, such as returning to the "default" strings configuration (i.e. the same configuration in the first page)?



Origin: When did the practice start?

Purpose: I think it wouldn't be much for the music typesetter / engraver to label each individual staff with the instrument abbreviation in subsequent pages, so I wonder what's the rationale behind labelling the 5 stave-string section (or the "default" configuration) "Archi".  Does it make it easier for conductors, so that by glancing that single word their mind automatically parse the whole string section "in default mode" so to speak?




Is "Archi" simply a shorthand for a system of 5 staves for Violin 1 + Violin 2 + Viola + Cello + Contrabass? For example, can "Archi" be used when there is only one violin part (i.e. 4 staves)? Or is there another meaning besides that shorthand, such as returning to the "default" strings configuration (i.e. the same configuration in the first page)?

My reading is that archi denotes the "default" disposition of strings as established on page one.  For a piece from the 18th or early 19th century, this would be four staves, as the cello and bass parts would share a staff.  I suppose that this practice is dictated by the "house style" of the publisher that engraved the score.  It's certainly not universal.  To identify the parameters governing its use, you'd need to do a survey of different publishers' practices.  It would be interesting to see whether this publisher ever did an edition of Brahms's Deutsches Requiem, the first movement of which has no violins, to see whether the practice of identifying the standard string choir is scoped separately for each movement or for the whole piece.

When did the practice start? What is it an abbreviation for, and in what language?

Divizna covered the language part as well as can be.  As I imagine you've realized on your own, the idiomatic English translation would be "strings," even if archi literally means "bows."  As to the time when the practice arose, I'd note that the practice of labeling staves on every page seems to have arisen in the middle or late 19th century; before that, they'd typically use the same disposition on every page of each movement, which makes for an inefficient use of copper and paper, but is somewhat less labor intensive because it requires less planning, and it is less ambiguous for the reader.  Once you start optimizing systems by removing staves for instruments that have nothing to play, it gets very confusing if you don't label every staff.  There are some related questions on this site, for example Partially-optimized orchestra scores?

I think it wouldn't be much for the music typesetter to label each individual staff with the instrument abbreviation in subsequent pages, so I wonder what's the rationale behind labelling the 5 stave-string section "Archi". Does it make it easier for conductors, so that by glancing that single word their mind automatically parse the 5 staves "in default mode" so to speak?

That's probably true (but remember that most scores from the 18th century or so to roughly the middle of the 20th are engraved, not typeset).  Since the purpose of these abbreviations is to be read quickly, someone probably decided, and reasonably so, that a single word for the entire standard string choir is best, because it requires the least mental processing.
But why not for the other sections?  The obvious answer is that the composition of the woodwind choir and brass choir are less standardized.  From 17th century, arguably, but certainly from the 18th century to the present, the standard string disposition has been two violin sections, one viola section, and a bass part; then in the 19th century it became increasingly common to write the cellos and contrabasses on separate staves.  There will hardly be any variation.  For woodwinds and brass, variation is constant: two, three, or four parts for each type of instrument, different kinds of instruments within each family, and so on, even entire pieces being written without instruments from a given family (e.g., no trombones at all), and so on.
So this publisher decided to label the full string choir Archi in abbreviation.  It would also have been reasonable to label each staff, and there are indeed publishers who do that.  I even have a score of Beethoven's fifth on my phone that omits the label for the full string choir but does use abbreviated labels for the winds and brass: the purpose of the group of four staves at the bottom of the system, two with treble clef, one alto, and one bass, is so obvious that no label is necessary.  Archi is indeed almost redundant, more a courtesy reminder than anything else.

What makes me wonder is why Rachmaninoff (or an editor) seems to label "Archi" only for the 2-1-1-1 segments of the score.

Because in those systems where the disposition is nonstandard, you need to tell the reader who's playing.  The clefs and the bracketing do that in the examples you've selected for the question, but they won't always, and, besides, the bracketing is easy to overlook.  The explicit label and the bracketing reinforce each other and help the reader understand as quickly as possible.

I was asking whether "Archi" conventionally can refer to any combination of the violin family once I establish the "default" scoring in the first page (say, 1 violin, 1 viola, 1 cello, 1 contrabass) rather than the more common 2-1-1-1.

I'm not sure you can say that there is any convention regarding the use of archi for this purpose.  I've never noticed it before.  If you did a survey of orchestral scores, you might find that not a single one using archi has a nonstandard string disposition, but then again it's entirely possible that the publishers who do or did use it never published (during the period when they were using archi) any orchestral music using a nonstandard disposition, so we can't "reverse engineer" their house style.
If archi makes you uncomfortable, just label all the staves.  As mentioned, some publishers do this.  If you like it, use it.  If your orchestra has a nonstandard string disposition, you can use it for the full complement of strings, whatever that may be.  See how your conductor or other readers of the score react.  I'd bet that most won't even notice.

I appreciate from your answer: 1) history of string disposition; 2) history of labeling staves and eliminating empty staves, 3) distinctions and more common terminologies such as engraver vs typesetter, publisher house style, disposition instead of configuration, etc. , 4) attempting to answer the origin question empirically.  As of now this is obviously the accepted answer but will wait a day or two to encourage other answers.  Thanks for taking the time!

"As I imagine you've realized on your own, the idiomatic English translation would be "strings," even if archi literally means "bows."" - Sorry about that. In Czech the term is also literally "bows" (smyčce), both for bowed instruments in general and for their section in an orchestra, so it never occured to me that English might invent something special.

@Divizna no need to be sorry.  Whether English came up with "strings" on its own or took it from another language using that term (probably French, if so; see GratefulDisciple's "good reference" at IMSLP), I do not know.  Obviously any name related to the bow is more specific.  Interestingly, German seems to have named the instruments after the act of bowing, using a verb related to stroke and strike with the sense of "rub."  In English, you see "strike" used in this sense at least to the end of the 17th century ("strike the viol, touch the lute"), but now it is certainly obsolete/archaic.

I believe it's also worth noticing that it's much more common to have a string section play in full as a "composite instrument" similar to a chorus, while that happens more rarely for other sections ("woodwinds", "brass", or "winds" in general) for various reasons, starting from the fact that even the standardized "smaller family" of wood winds have quite different "sound palettes" that are rarely used in an ensemble as strings are.

Archi means "bows", simple as that. (It's the plural of "arco", which is Italian for "bow".)

It would be great if you could elaborate on the origin of the practice as well and about why the typesetter uses that abbreviation for what apparently is a particular set of "bows", that is, 2 violins, 1 viola, 1 cell, and contrabass.  Does it ever used for another set of string instruments?

@GratefulDisciple It does not designate a particular set of instruments (although 2,1,1,1 is kind of the typical configuration for classical music), but simply the section of strings. If you think about it it makes a lot more sense: Why are harps and pianos not part of the string section? In Italian the string section is called “bowed instruments”, which in my opinion makes much more sense. But it is exactly the same thing as “strings”, just in Italian.

@Lazy Thanks.  So if I have an orchestral score that calls for only 4 staves (1-1-1-1), I can label the subsequent pages "Archi"?  What makes me wonder is why Rachmaninoff (or an editor) seems to label "Archi" only for the 2-1-1-1 segments of the score.

Found a good reference here.

@GratefulDisciple Will you be listing all the instruments in Italian? It wouldn't make much sense to switch languages there. (I'm sure you noticed that this score you've brought does list them all in Italian.)

@Divizna Yes, for the sake of this question.  At this point of the investigation, I just want to know whether "Archi" can be used for any combination of bowed instruments, as a shorthand on subsequent pages where in the first page I would mark explicitly which staff is for which instrument (in Italian).  Secondly, also to know the reason why the typesetter wouldn't simply keep the names of the instrument on subsequent pages, especially when the string scoring changes throughout the movement like in the Rach PC2 example; is that for readability for the conductor's sake?

@GratefulDisciple You should probably use it for the bowed section as a whole and not a subset, that'd be confusing. But what exactly that section comprises of in your ensemble can vary I guess. Re "What makes me wonder is why Rachmaninoff (or an editor) seems to label "Archi" only for the 2-1-1-1 segments of the score", I'll venture a speculation that it's to make it more readily apparent which part of the section it is that's left out, lumped together or split in two.

@Divizna Yes, of course that's what I intend to do (use "archi" for the whole string section).  And Yes, I agree with your speculation.  I guess I wasn't very clear.  I was asking whether "Archi" conventionally can refer to any combination of the violin family once I establish the "default" scoring in the first page (say, 1 violin, 1 viola, 1 cello, 1 contrabass) rather than the more common 2-1-1-1.  But secondly, why I want to label it "Archi" rather than using the instrument abbreviation in the subsequent pages?

@GratefulDisciple Again, Archi just means Strings. So ask yourself if it makes sense to write Strings instead of labelling each instrument. You will find that this is only viable if it is very clear what instruments are playing. E.g. if only second violin and celli are playing it would probably be really confusing to label them Strings.

@Lazy So looks like I'm overthinking this, then ?

@GratefulDisciple Yes, I think you're overthinking it.

@GratefulDisciple note that the IMSLP list shows abbreviations used on the IMSLP site -- they mention work lists -- rather than those one might find in a score.  The point is to provide a concise system for use in tables, where space is at a premium, and to provide a comprehensive unambiguous system that works across periods and styles.  (This is also the context in which one sometimes must distinguish c from C for key quality.)  Notice how these abbreviations don't all agree with the ones in this score but do allow you to distinguish cornetto, cornet, and countertenor.

@phoog Thanks for pointing that out, in a sense IMSLP is like a "house style", or more precisely a library catalog convention, since they only catalog, not do their own engraving.

Some remarks:

strings is a quite similar category name as archi, just in English instead of Italian.
It is a standard convention, to abreviate the names on follow-up pages, so paper can be saved. In fact, full scores have the convention, to have all instruments appear at the first page and may choose to omit the ones not playing afterwards. (It remains to be seen, whether electronic distribution with reduced cost effects will change that soon.)
The tendency to condense the most expected variants (all instruments playing) at the cost of having to be more specific in less frequent cases is really wide-spread and is unlikely to change in sheet music.


"It remains to be seen...": reducing page turns is useful in any context (unless you're placing ads in the score and want to reduce the amount of information users can see at once to force them to scroll).
